# unable to start Custom Component "AppCompatEditText" class

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-components

I am trying to create a custom AppCompactEditText, which I have created. I also created a sample app to test my custom component. However, When I call/input my custom edit text from the xml of sample app, It crashes and gives an error `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo`

Here is my code

```
class InputFields: AppCompatEditText{

private var mContext: Context
private var mAttrs: AttributeSet?
private var mDefStyleAttr: Int? = 0


constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
    mContext = context
    mAttrs = null
    init()
}


constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
    mContext = context
    mAttrs = attrs
    init()
}

constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    mContext = context
    mAttrs = attrs
    mDefStyleAttr = defStyleAttr
    init()
}

private fun init(){
 // this function initializes all the attributes
 // however when I debug it , it doesn't reach this block of code at all.
}
}
```

And I'm calling this in the sample app like this

```
<com.sample.inputfields.InputFields //line #26 ..The Error occurs on this line
            android:id="@+id/input_field"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
```

This is the error I get

```
05-08 11:07:24.130 31892-31892/? E/Zygote: isWhitelistProcess - Process is Whitelisted
05-08 11:07:24.133 31892-31892/? E/libpersona: scanKnoxPersonas
    Couldn't open the File - /data/system/users/0/personalist.xml - No such file or directory
05-08 11:07:30.079 31892-31892/com.sample.screenpatterns E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sample.screenpatterns, PID: 31892
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sample.screenpatterns/com.sample.sample.activities.InputFieldsSample}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.sample.inputfields.InputFields
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.sample.inputfields.InputFields
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #26: Error inflating class com.sample.inputfields.InputFields
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sample.inputfields.InputFields" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
05-08 11:07:30.081 31892-31892/com.sample.screenpatterns E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sample.sample.activities.InputFieldsSample.onCreate(InputFieldsSample.kt:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7174)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2908)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1696)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
        Suppressed: java.io.IOException: No original dex files found for dex location (arm64) /data/app/com.sample.screenpatterns-zfrxyrSPMGl2-va6c2wybw==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFileNative(Native Method)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.openDexFile(DexFile.java:353)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:100)
        at dalvik.system.DexFile.<init>(DexFile.java:74)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.loadDexFile(DexPathList.java:374)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.makeDexElements(DexPathList.java:337)
        at dalvik.system.DexPathList.<init>(DexPathList.java:157)
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.<init>(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
        at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.<init>(PathClassLoader.java:64)
        at com.android.internal.os.PathClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(PathClassLoaderFactory.java:43)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:69)
        at android.app.ApplicationLoaders.getClassLoader(ApplicationLoaders.java:36)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.createOrUpdateClassLoaderLocked(LoadedApk.java:678)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getClassLoader(LoadedApk.java:711)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:944)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.createAppContext(ContextImpl.java:2303)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5937)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
                ... 6 more
```

I have also imported the custom component/module the correct way as well.
Can someone please help me figure out what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add the full stack trace .

Comment: @ADM added stack trace.

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.sample.inputfields.InputFields"` ..  Your class name conflicts in error and in xml . Why ?

Comment: @ADM sorry that was an edit error. The class name in xml matches the class name of the component. It is recognized in the activity of the sample app as well.

Comment: Well this usually happens with proguard enable . Are you using proguard in debug mode also ?

Comment: Are you missing the package at the top of your class?

Comment: @ADM no I'm not using proguard for debug.

Comment: @ootinii no, I have imported all the packages needed.

Comment: @ADM I am also creating custom "AppCompatButton" the same way. It is working for the button, but not "AppCompatEditText"